# How can you create a multiple enum using jhipster-jdl?

Tags: jhipster

Let say that we have the following entities and the enum of languages:

```
entity Resources{
    title String required,
    text Language,
    audio Language
}

enum Language{
    SPANISH, ENGLISH, FRENCH, GERMAN
}
```

And we would like that the audio is a dropdown list where you can choose only one, but the text could be a list where you can choose more than one.

How can you tell Jhypster-JDL that you want to use an array of Languages?

It only lets you choose one... should it be done in the code once it is created?

Thanks

PD: I thought about that, but the problem with creating a language entity and define audio as a one-to-one relationship while text would be a one-to-many relationship like this is that the name variable gets repeated and crashes:

```
entity Resource{
title String required
}

entity Language{
    languages Languages
}

enum Languages{
    SPANISH, ENGLISH, FRENCH, GERMAN
}

// RELATIONSHIPS:
relationship ManyToOne {
    Language{resource(closedcaption)} to Resource
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Resource{language} to Language{resource(video)}
}

// Set pagination options
paginate Resource with pagination

// Set service options to all except few
service all with serviceImpl

@ManyToOne
private Resource resource;  <---

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "language")
@JsonIgnore
private Resource resource; <---
```

So, I might be making a mistake, but I would like to know if besides this solution, is there a way to have an array of something defined in JDL? Let's say an array of Strings?

Thanks again, you are really helpful!

Answer (score 4):

You could define Language as an entity and define audio as a one-to-one relationship while text would be a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Would it not be better to define a unidirectional many-to-one relationship from Resources{text} to Language?

Comment: Thanks, Gaël !!!!, I still have problems with that solution and at the same time I still would like to know if there is a way to have an array.

Comment: I don't understand why you used an enum field in entity Language, it was supposed to replace it, so Language entity should have one field of string type.

Comment: Thanks again Gaël. It makes sense to me :-(. That's what I understood you would do it. You can only choose one language for the audio, so an Enum is the logic choice, but you can choose more than 1 for text, so I added the One2Many relationship, right?. Can you type your solution in your answer so I can see it? It would really help. Thanks again